# How to Run a long SQL statement?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I am trying to write some R code that will pull information via SQL, the problem is that I have a very long Where statement because I am trying to check for a lot of things. As as result I am getting this error

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Statement is too
>   large. Statement Size: 159398497 bytes. Maximum Allowed: 16777216
>   bytes ) Error: C stack usage  159433302 is too close to the limit

Is there a workaround for this

Comment: convert to `stored procedure`

Comment: Are you saying that your query alone is over 16MB?

Comment: Please show a sample of *long WHERE statement*.

Comment: @Parfait judging by the error message, the where statement might be the better part of 160 MB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `WHERE` is occasionally known as the implicit join in SQL, you may be able to turn long running conditions into a table of values and join it to original recordset.

Original

```sql
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3 
FROM myTable t
WHERE (t.tool = 'r' AND t.backend = 'postgres')
   OR (t.tool = 'python' AND t.backend = 'mysql')
   OR (t.tool = 'julia' AND t.backend = 'sqlite')
   ...
```

Adjusted

```sql
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3 
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN myConditions c
   ON t.tool = c.tool
   AND t.backend = c.backend
```

myConditions

```sql
| tool   | backend  |
|--------|----------|
| r      | postgres |
| python | mysql    |
| julia  | sqlite   |
```